# On the Carmichael Lambda function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) be denoted by $\lambda(n)$.

Consider the set $I_m=\{n:\lambda(n)=m\}$.

1. What is known about the cardinality of $I_m$?

Let $P_m=\{p\in Primes: p|\ell \mbox{ for some }\ell\in I_m\}$.

2. What is known about the cardinality of $P_m$ and the size of product of primes in $P_m$?

Comment: For question 1, not much to judge by the paucity of the [relevant OEIS sequence (A321713)](http://oeis.org/A321713).